# Use temporary variable as colum name in mysql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have set a temporary variable with a column name:

```
SET @col_name:='my_column_name';
```

Now I want to use `@col_name` in a query as a column name.

```
UPDATE my_table SET @col_name='my new value';
```

But this gives me error.

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@col_name='my new value'' at line 1

Comment: Variables can only be used where expressions are allowed, not where names are required. To do this you need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

little trick with [prepare statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) and almost everything is possible ;)

```
SET @col_name:='my_column_name';
SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE my_table SET ',@col_name,'="my new value";');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable where a name is required, only where expressions are allowed. Here's a way to achieve what you want:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET col1 = IF(@col_name = 'col1', 'my new value', col1),
    col2 = IF(@col_name = 'col2', 'my new value', col2),
    col3 = IF(@col_name = 'col3', 'my new value', col3),
    ...
```

The alternative is dynamic SQL generation, as in Ochi's answer.